# Why there are differences between phpinfo() in PhpStorm and in Docker?

Tags: php, docker, phpstorm

Have you encountered problems with PhpStorm which sees other modules loaded by php.ini than is shown in Docker using `php --ini`?

For example:

These are modules which are shown by `php --ini` in Docker:

```
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_pgsql.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pgsql.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-wddx.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
```

These are modules which are seen by PhpStorm which is connected to the same docker container:

```
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini, 
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini, 
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini, 
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini, 
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini, 
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini, 
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini, 
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini, 
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini, 
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini, 
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini,
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini, 
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini, 
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini, 
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini, 
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini, 
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini, 
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini, 
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini, 
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini, 
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini, 
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini, 
/etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
```

Where the difference came from ? Do You have any ideas ? My system is Debian 8.

P.S. I have installed additional modules after I build docker image.

**EDIT: ANSWER:**

It is caused by adding php modules manually after docker image build. So if You want to avoid that inconvenience You must install all packages by Dockerfile. I am posting answer there because it is not describing why there is error like that. If You have any clues what have caused that feel free to share :)

Comment: Command line PHP and server mode PHP can use different INI files. See `php-cli.ini` versus `php.ini`.

Comment: I don't have any php-cli.ini file anywhere :/

Comment: I don't think this is to do with docker, I think it is a difference between php and phpstorm. How does phpstorm advise you of the list of modules? Is a filter applied? Is it gui? Is it its own phpinfo()?

Comment: I set CLI interpreter on Docker, it is set to use unix socket to connect to docker. I don't know what do You mean by filter or gui according to phpstorm and docker? Can You explain ?

Comment: Should not Docker have some sort of logger that allows to see all external commands that get passed/executed in this instance? f it does -- see what command PhpStorm executes. But most likely it will be `php -i` or `php -m` or alike.

Comment: My workmate suggest me that PHPStorm doesn't see any changes in phpmodules which have been made manually (not with Dockerfile), I will check it tomorrow.